Корректная связь базы данных с ботом Telegram на Python
Всем привет. Подскажите, как лучше всего поступить в моем случае. У меня есть два файла Python. Один - анкета пользователя, записывающая 10 параметров в бд (например p1, p2, ..., p10). А другой файл - результат работы с этими параметрами. Он неоднократно использует первые 8 параметров, остальные не задействованы и не нужны. Вопрос состоит в том, как лучше всего организовать связь бд со вторым файлом, работающем с параметрами p1, p2, ..., p8? Возможно и грамотно ли будет в самом начале файла дать запрос бд на извлечение в дальнейшем используемых параметров p1,p2, ..., p8, вместо того, чтобы вызывать каждый по необходимости (код большой, завязан в основном на формулах и условия). И как это будет влиять на общую производительность при большом количестве пользователей?
